# python flask mini-application global name not defined

Tags: python-2.7

I keep getting the error NameError: global name 'NameForm' is not defined
Here is my views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from app import forms


app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
         name = form.name.data
         form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name) 

if __name__  == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is my forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

class NameForm(Form):
"""docstring for ClassName"""
    name = StringField('Your name please', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Any ideas on what i might be doing wrong???

Comment: should 'form = NameForm()' not be 'form = forms.NameForm()' ??

Comment: alternatively if forms.py is within app/forms then you may need to add 'from forms import forms' (to views.py) to access NameForm within forms.py

Comment: @smoggers with addition of 'from forms import forms' results to an error since there is no module called forms

Comment: what about from app.forms import forms, I'm only assuming that forms.py is in a /forms directory? did forms.NameForm() make no difference either?

Comment: @smoggers the forms.py is in a  /app directory, the forms.NameForm() made no difference

Comment: ok I have deleted my answer, my last suggestion would be in views.py instead of 'from app import forms' try 'from forms import NameForm'